# Ruby on Rails database populate design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, csv

I have 2 csv files, the first containing thousands of area name/ID pairings, i.e.

```
ID, area_name
1, "New York"
2, "New Jersey"
```

etc...

And the second containing data about those areas, with the unique identifier being the ID not name (as the names are not unique in area_name).

```
area_id, field_1, field_2, field_3
1,       98,      48,      24
2,       10,      28,      45
```

I will ingest the first csv into postgres once and it will never change but I will get new lines of the second csv every few weeks or so that I will use to insert data into the DB.

My question is - What is the best way to store all of this in my DB as I need to display the area names to the users but when they select an area it needs to query the DB using the area_id and there are thousands of them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you store the first csv in a table called `Area` and place a has_one relation ship to the second model (eg. AreaDetails). Then you can query the second table through the first table.

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :area_detail, dependent: :destroy
end

class AreaDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :area
end
```

You can now fetch the area_details of area with id 1 by running:

```
Area.find(1).area_detail
```

I am assuming that you are deleting the 2nd table data when the data comes in. If you are keeping the data and need to show them all then you should use `has_many` instead of `has_one`.